Are there any examples of rollups with multiple types of blocks?
I'm curious if there are any examples of rollups that have more than one type of blocks?
Example of what kind of differences there could be between blocks:

Blocks of type Foo have 30M gas limit, whereas blocks of type Bar have 90M gas limit.
Block of type Foo allow certain only types of state transitions to occur, whereas Bar allows more.

The different types of blocks would still be contiguous, i.e. Foo block i is followed by Bar block i+1, which is followed by Foo block i+2. It wouldn't be possible to have both a Foo and a Bar block with number i+1.

Interesting idea. I would imagine this is difficult to implement, from many perspectives. A bit like trying to pick the good options from many chains, and probably failing to do any of that properly in the end.
